# I would like to git checkout an old version of a file from a remote branch into my local branch

Tags: git

I know how to get the latest version:
git checkout remotes/branchame filename, but not a prior version.

Comment: Note that if you only want one *particular* file, it's `git checkout <commit-specifier> -- <path-to-file>` (vs `git checkout <commit-specifier> .` to get everything as in the duplicate).

Comment: So, it's an *exact duplicate* of that question, but you have to explain how the answer is different in this case?  Interesting theory.

Comment: git checkout <commit-specifier> -- <path-to-file>.  So, what should <commit-specifier> look like?  remotes/branch abcd?  (abcd is the version number).